# Why changes python the 'from .. import ..' behaviour depending on script from the package

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-import

I'm working on my first package, and with this package, it's intended that you import it through 'from [MyPackage] import *' so that you don't have to write [MyPackage]. everytime. However, this package contains subpackages, so what I did was as follows:

__ init__.py

```
from subpackage1 import *
from subpackage2 import *
etc..
```

This way, you'd only have to do 'from [MyPackage] import *' once and it'd work. This was a good solution, until I decided I wanted it to make it at least possible to import the subpackages solely. I figured it'd be a good idea to create an extra subpackage called allmodules. This way, the same result would be achieved by 'from [MyPackage] import allmodules':

allmodules.py

```
from .subpackage1 import *
from .subpackage2 import *
etc..
```

However, this doesn't seem to work as it should, since none of the functions seem callable anymore by doing this. Why doesn't this work and how should this be fixed?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: `from x import *` isn't the greatest practice for a few reasons. If you want to eliminate the long calls, you can just rename your functions in your main module: `func1 = MyPackage.func1`.

Comment: @TheSoundDefense But I'd have to do that for every function, wouldn't I?

Comment: you would, yes. If you have a large amount it may not be practical. On the other hand, if you have variables in your modules that you're trying to import, `from x import *` isn't practical either, because the changed value of the variable is not shared between modules.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

`from MyPackage.allmodules import *` would do what you want.

Comment: @msw This is syntax. There's not much to learn other than to imitate.

Comment: That actually makes a lot of sense, stupid that I didn't think of that. Thanks!